# Convert ISO timestamp to UTC in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have strings with ISO timestamps like this:
`2015-03-07T10:02:37.720+01:00`
I want to convert it into UTC time.
Is there any API which gives me direct conversion?
(Application is in SpringBoot)

Comment: Learn about `java.time`

Answer (score 2):

This functionality can be found in the java.time package.

You can parse timestamps with the [DateTimeFormatter class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The pattern can be passed as an argument. In your case you can also use one of the predefined standard formats.

One of the options would be to use the [OffsetDateTime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for representing the time including the offset. Optionally, the [LocalDateTime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) can be used for representing the timestamp after parsing.

Example:

```
String myTime = "2015-03-07T10:02:37.720+01:00";
System.out.println("Input time: " + myTime);
OffsetDateTime offsetTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(myTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
LocalDateTime convertedTime = offsetTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println("UTC time:   " + convertedTime);
```

Output:

```
Input time: 2015-03-07T10:02:37.720+01:00
UTC time:   2015-03-07T09:02:37.720
```

Comment: Hey now I want to convert this UTC into locate datetime
Since I have to compare this data with my database data and in database the format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

Comment: For checking equality you will need to convert both to the same format. Either to string or for example the LocalDateTime class. For formatting a LocalDateTime to a string, you can use the DateTimeFormatter class.